# Customize the CheckedTextView for ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

As far as I know, the ListView embeds CheckedTextView to form the list, but every CheckedTextView has only one TextView and a CheckBox. What I want to do is adding some TextViews to the CheckedTextView, like this:

---

### TextView | TextView | TextView | CheckBox|   ---- CheckedTextView

---

How to customize the CheckedTextView? Any help will be appreciated！

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that you need to create a custom `LinearLayout` that implements `Checkable` and the create your `row.xml` using that custom `LinearLayout` which will work as `Checkable`. [`Here`](http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/) is a nice tutorial explaining the same with an example.

Comment: I have tried the [example](http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/), it works for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a custom layout for your ListView, perhaps:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Take the time to give this layout some personality. Now you can use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) or [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) to bind unique strings to each TextView.

Comment: Sam, I have tried Lalit Poptani's method and it works for me. Also, I learned some information about creating my customized [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) from your thread. Thanks!