# Custom a CheckedTextView in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, checkedtextview

I'm using a code that is not mine in my work.
This code uses CheckedTextView, do this:

```
...
    AlertDialog.Builder alert;
        v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
        switch (soundPreference.getType()) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) v;
            boolean checked = !checkedTextView.isChecked();
            ((CheckedTextView) v).setChecked(checked);
            switch (soundPreference.getKey()) {
            case SOUND_ACTIVE:

                sound.setAlarmActive(checked);
                break;
...
```

works perfectly, the problem is that I want I want to change the checkbox graphic.
Right now it looks like (defualt, I think):
[image]

and I want to get something like this:

[image]

if the CheckedTextView were defined in xml, know how to do it.
My problem is not being defined in xml, do not know how to do it.

I found this:
[Customize the CheckedTextView for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048145/customize-the-checkedtextview-for-listview)
but I do not know how to implement it

appreciate any help.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html#setCheckMarkDrawable%28int%29

Example:

```
myCheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
```

This method allows you to set the check mark image dynamically. You should call it when setting up the `CheckedTextView`.
The method in the developer reference just needs the id of the image resource you want to use.

There is also a version that takes a `Drawable` as a parameter instead of an id.

Comment: it's work but there's a problem. When pulse, called the method and the image changes, but when the activity starts, the image is displayed by default and I can not change it because the checkedTextView is created and associated with the view inside listview onListItemClick. How I can use this in the OnCreate method of the activity? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: CustomCheckBox]

You need to create a custom list_item layout.

For full explanation go through the below link...

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-custom-multiple-choice.html

Hope this will help you.